# Issue with getline() delimiter

Tags: c++, string, file, delimiter, getline

I am trying to read through a file and get specific strings on each line. The end of the string that i need is marked by a semicolon. I have no problems doing this, but I am noticing that getline() with the delimiter is automatically attaching a new line to my string.

```
 filename.open(FileName);
 while(filename)
  {
    getline(filename, name[counter], ';');

    filename >> amount[counter] >> unit[counter] >> calories[counter];
    counter++;

  }
```

So when i would go to print out the name array there would be 1 extra line break that I had not put there myself as if there was an extra '\n' being picked up along the way. Does anyone have a solution? An example of the file format that I am reading from is below.

Dave Jones; 24 Tall
Jillian Jones; 34 Short
etc...

Comment: The file format you show does not seem to match `>> amount[counter] >> unit[counter] >> calories[counter]`. Also, what happens when `counter++` exceeds the size of the arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running

```
filename >> amount[counter] >> unit[counter] >> calories[counter];
```

the newline is still in the buffer. This normally isn't a problem when you are using only ">>"; it just ignores newlines. But when you mix getline and ">>" you need to ignore the newlines that ">>" leaves behind. Try something like this:

```
filename >> amount[counter] >> unit[counter] >> calories[counter];
// Ignore first character or everything up to the next newline,
// whichever comes first
filename.ignore(1, '\n');
```

This is a bit redundant, but it's easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

Better way would be to read file line by line into a buffer and then split strings by ';':

```
while(true) {
    std::string line;
    std::getline( in, line );
    if( !in ) break;
    std::istringstream iline( line );
    while(true) {
        std::string str;
        std::getline( iline, str, ';' );
        if( !iline ) break;
        // you get string by string in str here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way to swallow the whitespace:

```
filename >> amount[counter] >> unit[counter] >> calories[counter] >> std::ws;
```